# How to capture words spread through multiple lines which have anywhite space(newline, space, tab)

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re

c = """
class_monitor std4:
    Name: xyz 
    Roll number: 123 
    Age: 9 
    Badge: Blue
class_monitor std5:
    Name: abc
    Roll number: 456
    Age: 10
    Badge: Red
"""
```

I want to print Name, Roll number and age for std4 and Name, roll number and badge for std5.

```
pat = (class_monitor)(.*4:)(\n|\s|\t)*(Name:)(.*)(\s|\n|\t)*(Roll number:)(.*)(\s|\n|\t)*(Age:)(.*)(\s|\n|\t)*(Badge:)(.*)
```

it matches the respective std if I toggle the second group (.*4:) to (.*5:) in pythex.

However, in a script mode, it is not working. Am I missing something here?